# How to access variable from the included header file

Tags: c++

I got three files, one which have the variables to be accessed and another two which need to access those variables. For now I am having three files like below and getting error in compilation which says undefined reference to i. I can not understand why is using a namespace giving an error?

header.h

```
extern int i;
```

a.cpp

```
#include "header.h"
#include "mheader.h"
namespace s{
  int i=10;
  struct p{
    p(){

    }
  };
}
```

b.cpp

```
#include "a.cpp"
int main(){
  cout<<i;
}
```

even if i define the define the variable i before starting namespace declaration it is not accessible inside namespace. Is there a way I can access the variable inside namespace as well as in b?

Comment: `i` and `s::i` are not the same thing, they're irrelevant.

Comment: even if i define it before starting namespace declaration it is not accessible inside namespace. Is there a way I can access the variable inside namespace as well as in b?

Comment: And why are you `#including` a CPP file?

Comment: I want that variable i to be accessible in both the file a.h and b.cpp. I searched for a solution and got a solution which stated the use of extern keyword to make the variable accessible in both these files. Is there a better way to accomplish this task?

Comment: @AdarshNair You want to access the globle `i` inside the namespace? Then `::i`.

Comment: @songyuanyao thanks that worked. I was unaware of global namespace.

Comment: well @songyuanyao it shows an error as 'i' in namespace :: does not name a type

Comment: @AdarshNair How do you use it?

Answer (score 2):

Namespaces are separate spaces for names. A name in one namespace refers to a completely different variable (or type or whatever) than a name in another namespace, unless specified otherwise.

`extern int i` declared in the global namespace (fully qualified name is `::i`) is a different variable than `int i`  defined in namespace `s` (fully qualified name is `s::i`).

As such, you never defined `::i` that you declared in header.h and used in b.cpp

There are two potential solutions, depending on what is your intention. You can define `int i` in the global namespace in either a.cpp or b.cpp. In that case you may want to get rid of `s::i` which is apparently not used anywhere.

Or, you can use `s::i` in b.cpp. In that case, you may want to get rid of the declaration of `::i` which would no longer be used anywhere.

As a sidenote, including a.cpp is most likely a mistake. If you ever try to link together object files compiled from both a.cpp and b.cpp, then you would be violating the one definition rule.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it this way.

**header.h**

```
namespace s
{    
extern int i;
}
```

**b.cpp**

```
    #include "a.cpp"
    int main()
    {
      cout<<s::i;
    }
```

But you better understand it well!

Comment: yes this works even if I do not use the keyword extern. But in case, if you can explain why that code is not working. I am being curious of how to make things work if they go real bad in some case like if I have an urgency to make other header file which can handle many variables of a large project that can be used in multiple files in that project

Comment: Consider: You placed a file in `C:\abc\file.txt`, but you are trying to read the file as if `c:\file.txt`. Consider the `extern` as shortcut to file `c:\file.txt`, which doesn't exist.